# Execute content script within new tab - chrome extentions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that scrapes some content from a particular website and then opens a new tab and does stuff with the scraped data.

Below is a test I made to see how I might do this. Unfortunately I can't seem to execute the `newtab-script.js` file as I get this error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot
>   access contents of url
>   "chrome-extension://FAKEIDgfdsgfdsgfdsgdsgfdsgFAKEID/newpage.html".
>   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
>       at Object.callback (chrome-extension://FAKEIDgfdsgfdsgfdsgdsgfdsgFAKEID/background.js:43:25)

## websitescrape.js

```
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.classList.add("web-scrape");
button.innerHTML = "scrape web";
document.querySelector('.placeIWantToPutButton').appendChild(button);

button.addEventListener('click', scrapeData);

function scrapeData(){
    //do website scraping stuff here...
    var fakedata = [{test:"data1"},{test:"data2"}];

    //send scraped data to background.js
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({setdata: fakedata}, function(tab){
        //callback
    });
}
```

---

## background.js

```
var dataTempStorage = [];

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.setdata) {
        dataTempStorage = request.setdata;

        chrome.tabs.create({
            'url': chrome.extension.getURL('newpage.html')
        }, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                file:chrome.extension.getURL("newtab-script.js")});
        });        
    }

    if (request == "getdata") {
        sendResponse({data: dataTempStorage});
    }    
});
```

---

## newtab-script.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("getdata", function (response) {
    doStuff(response.data);
});

function doStuff(){
    //Do staff on newpage.html with data scraped from original page
}
```

---

## newpage.html

```
// page ready to be filled with awesome content!
```

Comment: FYI, it's usually helpful to post the manifest of the extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Cause**: content scripts can't be injected into extension pages with `chrome-extension://` scheme.

**Solution**: since you have control over that html page just reference the content script file explicitly.

newpage.html:

```
        <script src="newtab-script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And don't use `executeScript`.

Comment: Awesome! So simple haha! I'll accept answer in 5mins.
Thanks for helping me out @wOxxOm :)

Comment: you REALLY helped me! =D Tks