# How to get the window object of a tab created with 'chrome.tabs.create()'?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open a new tab and then executing a content-script within the context of that new tab. I tried to do it like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'main.html' }, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: 'console.log(window.name)'
    });
});
```

But that doesn't seem to be working, is there any way I can reach directly to the window object of my newly created tab (something like `chrome.extension.getViews({tabId: tab.id})`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute content script within new tab - chrome extentions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33845125/execute-content-script-within-new-tab-chrome-extentions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are calling is a page that belongs to your extension.
A content script cannot be injected in extension pages in Chrome, so best option is to include the content script as a script in the page itself.

Add a `<script>` tag to the page header, and run the code there.

If needed, you can use `localStorage` in order to transfer data/values to the page before loading it.

*Sources:*

- developer.chrome: [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: As it turns out, there is an open feature request here (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72418) for exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it didn't get the chance to be implemented, so I've to come up with some kind of a polyfill/workaround. Any thoughts on how I may achieve that would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a major security issue, and I expect it won't be implemented. As for a workaround, use messaging or localStorage to pass arguments to the page, and execute code from within. Remember you are in full control of the page..